# Create new column from existing column in Dataset - Apache Spark Java

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I am new to `Spark ML` and got stuck in a task which require some data normalization and there is very less documentation available on net for Spark ML - Java. Any help is much appreciated.

Problem Description :

I have a `Dataset` that contains encoded url in column (`ENCODED_URL`) and I want to create new column (`DECODED_URL`) in existing Dataset that contains decoded version of ENCODED_URL.

For Eg : 
**Current Dataset**

ENCODED_URL
https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite

**New Dataset**

```
ENCODED_URL                         | DECODED_URL  
https%3A%2F%2Fmywebsite             | https://mywebsite
```

Tried using `withColumn` but had no clue what i should pass as 2nd argument

```
Dataset<Row> newDs = ds.withColumn("new_col",?);
```

After reading the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#sqltransformer) got an idea that it may be possible with SQLTransformer but couldn't figure out how to customize it to decode the url.

This is how i read information from CSV

```
Dataset<Row> urlDataset = s_spark.read().option("header", true).csv(CSV_FILE).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY());
```

Answer (score 1):

#### A Spark primer

The first thing to know is that Spark `Datasets` are effectively immutable. Whenever you do a transformation, a new Dataset is created and returned. Another thing to keep in mind is the difference between `actions` and `transformations` -- actions cause Spark to actually to start crunching numbers and compute your DataFrame while `transformations` add to the definition of a DataFrame but are not computed unless an action is called. An example of an action is `DataFrame#count` while an example of a transformation is `DataFrame#withColumn`. See the full list of actions and transformations in the [Spark Scala documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).

#### A solution

`withColumn` allows you to *either* create a new column or replace an existing column in a `Dataset` (if the first argument is an existing column's name). The docs for `withColumn` will tell you that the second argument is supposed to be a `Column` object. Unfortunately, the [Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) documentation only describes methods available to `Column` objects but does not link to other ways to *create* `Column` objects, so it's not your fault that you're at a loss for what do next.

The thing you're looking for is [`org.apache.spark.sql.functions#regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#regexp_replace-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). Putting it all together, your code should look something like this:

```
...
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

Dataset<Row> ds = ... // reading from your csv file
ds = ds.withColumn(
    "decoded_url", 
    functions.regexp_replace(functions.col("encoded_url"), "\\^https%3A%2F%2F", "https://"))
```

`regexp_replace` requires that we pass a `Column` object as the first value but nothing requires that it even exist on any `Dataset` because `Column` objects are basically instructions for *how* to compute a column, they don't actually contain any real data themselves. To illustrate this principle, we could write the above snippet as:

```
...
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

Dataset<Row> ds = ... // reading from your csv file
Column myColExpression = functions.regexp_replace(functions.col("encoded_url"), "\\^https%3A%2F%2F", "https://"))
ds = ds.withColumn("decoded_url", myColExpression)
```

If you wanted, you could reuse `myColExpression` on other datasets that have an `encoded_url` column.

#### Suggestion

If you haven't already, you should familiarize yourself with the [`org.apache.spark.sql.functions` class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html). It's a util class that's effectively the Spark standard lib for transformations.